# 'GUTS' and Cast your Guts !spell again? in this Context

Tags: slang

I see this dialogue in Code Geass episode 3 in subtitles and I did not understand what is meant by GUTS! and Cast your Guts! spell again?

Girl1: Rivalz, Can't you take being a student council member more seriously?
Girl2: you should have reminded us about the deadline a day earlier 
Rivalz: I'd have prefered a day later. Then we'd given up already 
Lelouch: Good idea. For now, at least
Girl1: GUTS! (shouting with a very high voice)
Rivalz: Casting your Guts!spell again?

Comment: [*Generally when one undertakes harmful spell work -- and a vinegar jar is always harmful -- it is a good idea to perform protection work to keep the space clear of incursions, and and to humbly perform a cleansing ritual afterward for the good of one's own soul. Protection is especially necessary when one is performing a coercive "**Spill Your Guts**" type of **Compelling bottle spell**.*](http://www.luckymojo.com/bottlespells.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the printed representation of spoken text, ALL CAPS are often use to represent shouting.  And "casting your Guts! spell again" just implies that Girl1 is known to shout this word, and Rivalz is aware of this.  Rivalz either interprets Girl1's shout as an attempt at magic or is being sarcastic, it's hard to say which.